# How can I create hyperlink in Acronyms in latex

Tags: latex, acronym

How can I make my acronyms such that if someone clicks on acronyms then gets redirected to the actual list where all the acronyms are listed?

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\input{acronyms}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]

\chapter{ch1}
\acrfull{WLAN} is used as a trial for my example and problem

\chapter{ch2}
\acrfull{LAN} is used as a trial for my example and problem
\arcshort{LAN}

\end{document}
```

with acronyms.tex:

```
\newacronym{WLAN}{WLAN}{Wireless Local Area Network}
\newacronym{LAN}{LAN}{Local Area Network}
```

Comment: There is a typo in `\acrshort`

Comment: yes, I corrected it and ist working well now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the `hyperref` package will give you cross-references between your acronyms and the list of acronyms:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newacronym{WLAN}{WLAN}{Wireless Local Area Network}
\newacronym{LAN}{LAN}{Local Area Network}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]

\chapter{ch1}
\acrfull{WLAN} is used as a trial for my example and problem

\chapter{ch2}
\acrfull{LAN} is used as a trial for my example and problem

\end{document}
```

Comment: It works well with \acrfull{} But is there any way I can make hyperref when using \acrshort{}?

Comment: I get a hyperlink for `\acrshort`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPHNn.png

Comment: yes Now it did for me also thankyou. :)

Comment: i wish i could add you as my co-author in my thesis document :p